# Зависимость взаимного расположения блоков в сетке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Из кода убрал лишние элементы, оставил только каркас.
Проблема такая: когда правый блок `right_block` наполняется контентом, то блок `content` начинает cдвигаться вниз.
Блоки `bread`, `content` и `first_text_box` находятся слева от `right_block`. Как это можно исправить?

Картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-17 col-md-15 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
            <div class="bread">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-9 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
            <div class="right_block">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-17 col-md-17 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
            <div class="content">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-17 col-md-17 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
            <div class="first_text_box">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bread {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #dddcdc;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
.right_block {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #dddcdc;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 240px;
    border: 2px solid #dddcdc;
    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо разместить "левые" блоки в одной "колонке", тогда они не будут зависеть от высоты правого блока. Ибо, в противном случае, левый+правый блок действуют так, будто они объединены общим контейнером `.row` - сдвигают всё, что ниже вследствие увеличения своей высоты:

```
    <div class="col-lg-17 col-md-15 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
        <div class="bread">

        </div>
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-9 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
        <div class="right_block">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Кроме того, если в проекте используется сетка из 24 колонок, то для экранов среднего размера ошибка в разметке:

```
     <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="right_block">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-17">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
```

`col-md-9` + `col-md-17` не равно `col-md-24` - отсюда и сползание контента

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил. Но эта ошибка появилась уже позже, когда я решил для md изменить размеры)) Да, не поменял для нижних блоков. Сейчас исправил, но основная проблема не решилась...

Comment: @ArturMark дополнил ответ

Comment: Сделал так, но теперь либо правый блок уходит влево (т.к. его код начинается раньше остальных), либо, если его код кинуть под остальные, то сам блог уходит вниз. Почему в первом случае перестает работать float? Ведь там указано left и right...

Comment: Все, разобрался! Большое спасибо